# Showing statistics about area or percentages of coverage in the legend titles

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a multicolumn  spatial data . I added the data to geoserver and add different styles to that layer based on different columns and then I visualize it with mapstore.

The geometries are polygons and the styles are simply different color(fill, stroke).
and the legend is composed of the titles that show the ranges for different colors,

Now I want to have some statistics in the titles so

Instead of showing for example : `[color red]  0 --- 10`

I want to show :

```
[red ]00 --- 10 (10 ha. --- 10%)
[blue]10 ---20 (1 ha. ---- 1%)
....
```

The simple way to do it is to add the statistics to the titles but for each new set of spatial data I have to create new styles and calculate the statics manually and add them.

Is there any way to do it in SLD file so I create only one file and then add it to any new layers and it calculates the statistics automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to do this without generating a new SLD for each file.

If you want to suggest an enhancement (and provide the code or money) it might be possible to make the `Rule`s `Title` element take a `Expression` rather than the fixed string it currently expects. Then you could use a value from a feature or an environment variable. Or it may be possible to generalize the feature count code to take a user supplied function.